# How to get Mouse Click Event From Code Behind in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**How can I Pass Mouse Click Event to JavaScript function from code behind.**

```
  imgTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return Test('" + sUrl + "','" + txtTest.ClientID + "','"
            + hdnTestId.ClientID  + "');");

function Test(sUrl,TestName,TestId){
    
}
```

How can I Get Click Event Test JavaScript Function

*I Have Try eventargument not worked Please Below Code*

```
EventArgs e  = new EventArgs();
imgTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return Test('" + sUrl + "','" + txtTest.ClientID + "','"
            + hdnTestId.ClientID  + "','" +  e + "');");

function Test(sUrl,TestName,TestId,EventArg){
    
}
```

Note :- I can't change Calling mechanism..

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wire up a client side event?

You can always drop in a button on the page - hide it with style="display:none"

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdRunServerCode" runat="server" Text="Button"  style="display:none" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    <script>

        function mytest() {
            // do whatever
            // now run server side button code
            $('#cmdRunServerCode').click()
            
        }

    </script>
```

So, you can use js to "click" the hidden button to run that button code stub you have server side.